# push notification to predefined group in database using signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, notifications, signalr

I am trying to send notification to specific groups created in database (not signalR groups to which users join using signalR) using signalR.

For example, a user has created an event and invited 2 people, all notifications related to that event must be brodcasted to only users invited.
The same for another event.

I have looked for such a solution but i didn't find what i actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my need. I will use tha mapping of users to connection Id with customized IUserIdProvider as described in the link below [mapping-signalr-users-connections-using-iuseridprovider](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/mapping-signalr-users-connections-using-iuseridprovider/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to utilize signalr groups as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups).

Then assuming you are keeping track of the userid that is in your database group you could send to that specific userid or userids.

Clients.Client(userid).sendMessage(message);

Comment: But does Clients.Client(userid) refer to the user id from database table? Because what i meant is that when a user creates an event and invite people to it, a record will be added to events table and to group table with concerned users.

Comment: In it's purest sense no, it refers to the userid of the client as currently connected, SignalR creates and assigns to the client. If you are taking that userid and updating your database with the user's current userid then it could be the same. It sounds like you need to work through managing clients in your database to understand how you can leverage that.